# Next.js hydration error while mapping an icon

Tags: next.js

i'm getting a hydration error in next js

[here in the div where I used the star icon, I'm getting a
hydration error I read the documents using useEffect but didn't work,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muc8x.png)

Comment: Can u share the code instead of SS and provide little more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a random initial state value `const [rating] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)` that you then use in your map to display the icons, the static HTML you generate on the server sometimes has a different amount of `StarIcon`s then what the browser expects during React hydration because the state-initialization happens both during SSR and client-side execution/hydration.

If you want to use server-side rendering and have a random initial value for `rating` for each user request, you'd have to use SSR instead of SSG and generate the random value for `rating` inside `getServerSideProps` and pass it down to the page-component so that it stays the same for server and client.

An easier (and better imo) way to fix this without SSR would be not statically pre-rendering the star icons and just let them be  ***client-side rendered*** like this:

```
export default function Cards(props: any) {
  const [rating] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  const [hasPrime] = useState(Math.random() < 0.5);

  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false); // <-- add this

  useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true); // <-- toggle on client-side, because useEffect doesn't run on server-side/during SSG build
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="z-30 [...]">
      {/* [...] your other JSX elements */}

      {/* Only render the StarIcons on client-side, as hasMounted will always be false on server-side */}
      {hasMounted && (
        <div className="flex">
          {Array(rating)
            .fill(rating)
            .map((_, i) => (
              <StarIcon className="h-6" />
            ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```